# Backspace not working in ubuntu terminal

Tags: command-line

Till yesterday the backspace was working perfectly . But something happened and backspace stopped working in the terminal alone . Backspace is working perfectly in other cases ..like in a normal text editor and all ..everything is normal ..except the terminal thing ..so can someone please help me ? I use ipython a lot ..so i desperately need the backspace to work ..

thanks in advance

Comment: Try installing another terminal emulator. It might be an error in the config file.

Comment: Try using xfce4-terminal. You can install it by doing sudo apt-get install xfce4-terminal

Comment: @Supercooldude283 Can you post the result of `echo $0` in terminal??? Please

Answer (score 2):

As I think your Del, Tab and arrow keys also didn't work. If you did `echo $0` and you see `/bin/sh` then you need to set your your shell to `/bin/bash` instead. So run `chsh -s /bin/bash` to change your login shell to `bash` and check again your keys(Backspace, Del, Tab and arrow keys) if fixed.

Or you can make sure that your TTY is configured with the right characters by checking the output of `stty -a`, and setting the erase character to match what's being sent with `stty erase ^?`.

If you run `stty -a | grep -w erase`, you will see something like this:

> intr = ^C; quit = ^\; **erase = ^?**; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = M-^?;
>   eol2 = M-^?;

If that is different changing login shell to `bash` solve your problem but if didn't solve you can run `stty erase ^?` to solve the problem and also did the same for your another keys(Del, Tab, Arrow keys).